# xv-11-lidar cannot find the right port

Tags: ros, lidar, xv-11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu mate 20.04 focal and i have installed ros noetic,
i'm following the following tutorial
http://wiki.ros.org/xv_11_laser_driver/Tutorials/Running%20the%20XV-11%20Node

when i try to run the following command

rosrun xv_11_laser_driver neato_laser_publisher port_:=/dev/ttyACM0

I get the following error: [ERROR] [1582038870.703246684]: Error instantiating laser object. Are you sure you have the correct port and baud rate? Error was open: No such file or directory

in the tutorial when i try to run the following command it says "error file doesn't exist"

## echo 'SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", SYMLINK+="sensors/ftdi_%s{serial}"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/52-ftdi.rules

when i change 52-ftdi.rules to the actual file that is in the rules.d folder which is 70-snap.snapd.rules
it says "permission denied"

when i run dmesg -w i get the following output
usb 1-1.2: Product: USB Serial
usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Teensyduino
usb cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.0 ttyACM0: USB ACM device

when i run lsusb i get the following
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 16c0:0483 Van Ooijen Technische Informatica Teensyduino Serial
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 046d:0892 Logitech, Inc. OrbiCam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

i'm not sure if the problem is because the rosrun instruction isn't getting the right port? if this is the problem then how do i change the permissions in the 70-snap.snapd.rules file? or if the problem is due to something else?

the lidar does turn when i plug it in and as far as i can tell it's not a hardware issue.....

please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376205/xv-11-lidar-cannot-find-the-right-port/) by [golferGuy1145](https://answers.ros.org/users/73323/golferguy1145/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may not have enough permission to execute the device file.
( /dev/ttyACM0 exists, but cannot be opened from neato_laser_publisher )

```
$ sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0
```

and then run

```
$ rosrun xv_11_laser_driver neato_laser_publisher port_:=/dev/ttyACM0
```

You can also try

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [golferGuy1145](https://answers.ros.org/users/73323/golferguy1145/) on 2021-04-15**:
i tried running sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0

but it still gave me the same error
[ERROR] [1582038870.703246684]: Error instantiating laser object. Are you sure you have the correct port and baud rate? Error was open: No such file or directory

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-15**:
$ ls /dev/tty*

What do you see when you do this? Does /dev/ttyACM0 or /dev/ttyUSB0 exist?

**Comment by [golferGuy1145](https://answers.ros.org/users/73323/golferguy1145/) on 2021-04-16**:
it worked after i ran sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0 and then re-did a catkin_make so thanks

**Comment by [golferGuy1145](https://answers.ros.org/users/73323/golferguy1145/) on 2021-04-16**:
However, when i run rosrun rviz rviz it's not showing any output from the lidar which so i'm not sure what that means?

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-04-16**:
You will need to configure rviz. Add the [scan topic](http://wiki.ros.org/xv_11_laser_driver#Published_Topics) display. This is becoming different from the original question, so please create another question if this comment does not solve the problem.

ref : http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide#Displays